# NodeJS+MySQL instead of PHP+MySQL. Is it ok?

Tags: mysql, web-applications, node.js

I've read about NodeJS but couldn't find its dis/advantages. Can i replace a PHP/MySQL application with NodeJS/MySQL? is it good idea?

Please consider a PHP CMS. Can NodeJS do as well as PHP? Is NodeJS only suitable for some lightweight actions?

If it is ok, which MySQL module is the best one?

Comment: I would recommend against mysql in favour of couchdb/mongodb/redis/riak/nosql/etc

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Before getting into Node.js hype, [read the following article](https://web.archive.org/web/20111129135817/http://teddziuba.com/2011/10/node-js-is-cancer.html).

Basically, Node.js HAS issues.
It's a server, but you can connect to MySQL via Node and send data to the user. There are many pitfalls, one of them being that you must know JS and you'll have to format your output via JS instead of PHP.

However, your bottleneck will almost never be PHP, unless you do some stuff that PHP wasn't designed for (like loading 1 million entries in an array and doing various searches using that array and what not).
What you'll find to be your bottleneck (in case of a busy website) is the HTTP server since you'll probably exceed memory due to each connection requiring certain amount of memory and of course - your DB will be (most likely) I/O bound (hdd bound).

In this whole process, PHP will be the least of your worries. Using programs written in C or for Node won't help speed things up, as you'll have to scale your database system - which is a whole different story (plus you'll need to scale your HTTP server setup).

Basically - stick with PHP/MySQL, forget about Node, at least for now.

Update: since this answer is accepted and technology caught up, it's good to warn new people: Node.js became popular beyond anyone's wildest dreams and I personally find it **awesome**. I'm lucky enough to be able to use both node and php interchangeably.

Node has great community and awesome packages, package managers and task runners. Anyone familiar with JS is able to work with node instantly. It's great, extremely useful and I see node as something that will propel JavaScript to do what Java was originally designed for (this is opinion based on anecdotal evidence and not a fact).

Bottom line: when choosing a technology, one should choose the one that they're familiar or expressive with. Both PHP and Node.js are great in its own way, there is no definitive way of determining which one is "better".

Comment: +2 from me. PHP is mature- Version 5x+ has APC rolled in, and a stable PDO implementation. I've only seen the wheel reinvented with NodeJS- same crap you can do with PHP/MySql- but with new problems. Look around Stack Overflow. Every problem that has ever been encountered with PHP is here, with a working solution. Unless you are building a soft real time application, which is marginally easier with NodeJS, I say hold off on drinking the NodeJS koolaid- even today. While doing lower level things with JS is neat, it doesn't solve the age- old problem of poor design, the biggest problem there is.

Comment: Did you just try and link the "Node JS is Cancer" article that everyone has debunked and which has been deleted since? (whoops this is late)

Answer (score 7):

You can. Its fast.

Benchmarking : 
http://zgadzaj.com/benchmarking-nodejs-basic-performance-tests-against-apache-php

Interaction with MySQL is pretty complex. If you have a firm background on node.js it shouldn't be a problem. 
But the PHP developers have made interaction with MySQL the easiest and cleanest.

http://www.giantflyingsaucer.com/blog/?p=2596

http://utahjs.com/2010/09/22/nodejs-and-mysql-introduction/

For me, I'd use PHP / MySQL

Comment: I've seen that but what about highly MySQL interactives?

Answer (score 5):

It would be helpful if you wrote a bit detail about your php application. The decision will depend on lot many things, like -

1. How vast is your application? It will impact the time you need to port a php application to node. You may also have to consider you expertise on async style programming in javascript.
2. You wrote you are at the optimization step. Php is there for a long time. It should be easier to apply optimization techniques than rewriting everything in a different platform at this late stage, of course I'm assuming that time is a crucial factor for you, as it is in software industry.
3. How slow your application is? Is it executing slowly or not scaling up with increased load? Language performance is hardly the bottleneck for web applications. Have you tried optimizing your queries, adding proper indexing to your db, trying a better web server and/or caching? Look around, you'll get several times more resource on how to optimize php applications than how to do something in node.
4. Have you considered investing on hardware? May that be a cheaper option than redoing everything?

To be short, node is still exploring its possibilities, if you want to learn it, now is the best time. But if that learning involves messing with production level applications, my suggestion is no. node will not magically improve the performance of your application, it was not built for that purpose.

To answer your another question- most people prefer Felixge's MySQL driver: https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql

And here is another alternative: https://github.com/sidorares/nodejs-mysql-native

Answer (score 2):

If you have a large existing mysql database that you need to interact with full of legacy code that will be a nightmare to convert to nosql then yes.

Otherwise no, use couch/mongo/redis/riak/cassandra/etc.

Pick a solid noSQL database that fits your requirements.

As for whether node can do what php/mysql can do yes. You can develop websites with it.

Does node have the equivelant of drupal or wordpress that holds your hand and does everything for you? No.

Comment: I am a PHP developer and don't want something to work as a fast CMS. I am working on a web application with highly relational database. We are in optimization steps and what we need today is performance.
As i read about nodejs, it is fast in many cases. Now i want to know, replacing PHP with NodeJS will help me?

Comment: @AHHP If you need performance try optimising your PHP and compiling it down to C. If that doesn't work use erlang instead, want performance use erlang or C.

Comment: @AHHP: Optimize your database, PHP will hardly be the bottleneck.

Answer (score 2):

You can use https://github.com/masuidrive/node-mysql or https://github.com/sdepold/sequelize . it's one of the best mysql driver for nodejs

Answer (score 1):

I am not well experienced in NodeJS. But my points are,

1. Nodejs is built for creating real-time applications like Chat, Online gaming etc., Because it is really fast.
2. NodeJS is a server. So you cannot compare with php, Meaning that you need to go for the third party modules to perform some tasks such as expressjs, node-mysql etc.,
3. Creating application with NodeJS is really simple like php-mysql